# Installing multiple packages in sublime text 3

Tags: package, installation, sublimetext3

When installing packages in Sublime Text 3, is there anyway I can tick all the ones I want from a list, and then install them in one go?  Or do I have to click Preferences > Package Control > Install Package, for every single package I'd like to install?  Notepad++ for instance has a nice list with checkboxes...

Answer (score 11):

Just use Preferences > Package Control > **Package Control: Advanced Install Package**.

Then you can enter a comma-separated package list, e.g. `ConvertToUTF8,MarkdownEditing,SublimeLinter,SublimeREPL`.

Also, note that you could just press <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> (on OS X) or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> (on Windows) and type the command name (Package Control: Advanced Install Package) or even part of it, like `pcaip`. This will be much faster than clicking menu entries.

Answer (score 7):

[@wbond](https://github.com/mrmartineau/SublimeTextSetupWiki/issues/3#issuecomment-5301745) said:

To batch install other packages, a `Package Control.sublime-settings` file needs to be placed into the `Packages/User/` folder.

Inside of the settings file should be a JSON object (`Package Control.sublime-settings`) with the key `"installed_packages"` that references a list of package names. When Package Control starts, if any of those packages are not present, the will be automatically downloaded and installed. Here is an complete example:

`{
        "installed_packages":
        [
                "ApacheConf.tmLanguage",
                "Package Control",
                "SublimeLinter"
        ]
}`

After adding the packages you want to on `Package Control.sublime-settings`, just restart Sublime Text and the Package Control will start installing those packages.

Comment: Perfect answer! Open console window immediately after restart to see activities.