# Sublime Text 3: Master Config? (for: disaster recover, porting to new machine, etc.)

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor

I'm new to Sublime Text 3, but I really like it so far.  I'm spending a lot of time getting to know the program, installing useful packages, etc.

Q: Is there a smart way to save/archive your configurations periodically?  I'm thinking down the road about Disaster Recovery, setting up a new machine, etc.

I did find this answer [installing multiple packages in sublime text 3, answered by Thomas Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581626/installing-multiple-packages-in-sublime-text-3)

Batch installation of packages is smart. I can set up a comma-separated package list and just let ST3 take care of the installation; however, that's only for packages.

Can the same be done for EVERYTHING?  (Packages, Preferences, Snippets, et. al?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, any customizations that you make to Sublime end up as files in your `User` package, which you can see by selecting `Preferences > Browse Packages...` from the menu.

Example contents of the `User` package include (but is not limited to):

- Modifications to settings, which are stored in `sublime-settings` files. This is true for both Sublime settings (`Preferences.sublime-settings`) as well as the settings that you have customized for any packages that you have installed (for example `Package Control.sublime-settings`).
- Any snippets you have created, which are stored in `sublime-snippet` files
- Any plugins you have created, which are stored in `py` files.
- Your own specific customizations to Sublime resources, either from core Sublime or from other packages. This includes things like `sublime-menu`, `sublime-keymap`, `sublime-commands`, `sublime-color-scheme` and so on

As such, pretty much every customization that you may have done to Sublime is related to that folder, which means that if you want to save your Sublime setup you want to save the contents of that folder somewhere. This also means that when you set up a new computer you can use that saved copy to get the new machine ready to go.

It's highly recommended that you use Package Control to install packages; based on your question above I assume that you're doing that. The good news for you is this: the `Package Control.sublime-settings` file (which is stored in your `User` package) contains a list of all of the packages that you've told Package Control to install.

When you start Sublime, one of the things that Package Control will do is verify that the list of packages that you've told it to install are currently installed, and if they're not, it will install them for you.

This means that to set up a new machine with a Sublime install, you can install Sublime, install Package Control, copy your saved `User` package into the appropriate location, and start Sublime; Package Control will automatically install all of your packages for you without having to follow the steps outlined in the answer you linked in your question.

In fact there is a page in the [Package Control Documentation](https://packagecontrol.io/docs) that describes how to [Sync your User Package](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/syncing) to do this very thing.

The `Packages` folder that your `User` package is stored in, as well as the `Installed Packages` folder that Package Control installs packages into are stored in the Sublime `Data` folder; the area where Sublime stores files specific to your user on your computer.

If you're using Sublime on Windows and you've used a Portable installer, this folder is stored inside of the Sublime install location. In all other cases (i.e. "normal" windows installs, or on MacOS or Linux) the `Data` folder is stored in your home directory and is left alone should you uninstall or reinstall Sublime.